# Change north/south orientation in Android MapView

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to change the north/south orientation in a MapView based on two GeoPoints:

- One starting point will be the southmost point
- One ending point will be the northmost point

So if you would draw a line between the two points, this would be a straight line from south to north. Is there any way to align the map this way?

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't solved this yet, you can rotate the map however you'd like.

http://code.google.com/p/cameralert/wiki/RotateTouches

That contains the ability to rotate based on the compass sensor. For you I'd just set the rotation to 180 and remove the location sensor updates.